# Setting Broker properties on an Azure Service bus message - python

Tags: python, azure, properties, azureservicebus, content-type

I have a relatively simple question. I have been successfully writing Json string messages to a queue on an azure service bus.

I have been able to assign a Label under the broker-properties however when I try to assign the 'ContentType', it is not successful.

this is my code for sending a message & setting the properties as shown on the azure website

```
'''
for json_item in resultlist:
  jsonData= json.loads(json_item)
  msg = Message(format(json_item).encode('utf-8'),
                     broker_properties = {"Label": "M1", 
                                          "ContentType": "application/json"})
  sbs.send_queue_message(queue, msg)
'''
```

Instead the ContentType, when I read the queue message is set to "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8"

Any pointers would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Is `"application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8"` response content type or the value of `ContentType` property?

Comment: Hi Gaurav - it is the value of the ContentType property under the message system properties

Answer (score 1):

I found this documentation poor also. It doesn't help that the Python 'azure.servicebus' library has been re-written a few times over and keeps changing so examples on the web are very confusing. 
Using the latest preview version of the service bus library (at time of writing):
azure-servicebus==7.0.0b3

I was able to set the content type to 'application/json' (and also set custom fields) through the following code:

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, Message
...

with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(MY_SERVICEBUS_CONN) as client:
    with client.get_queue_sender(MY_QUEUE_NAME) as sender:
        custom_props = {
            'my_custom_field': 'yay!',
        }
        message = Message(json.dumps(payload))
        message.user_properties = custom_props
        message.properties.content_type = 'application/json'
        sender.send(message)
```

Hope this helps!